# Iterating Over a String in Threes

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, iteration

Say I have string:

```
string = 'ABCDEFGHI'
```

and I want to iterate over the string so the output will be:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Is this feasible?  Can I just do something along the lines of:

```
for i in string, 3:
  print i
```

I feel like there is an easier solution that I am missing.

Comment: Is the length guaranteed to be divisible by 3?  How do you want to handle the case where the string is `'ABCDEFGHIJK'`?

Comment: I have a method that ensures the string is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `for` loop to accomplish this would be:

```
for i in range(3, len(string) + 1, 3): 
    print string[i-3:i]
```

Which uses a [`step=3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) value for `range()` to iterate by `3's` and then, utilizing a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) object which depends on the value of `i` you get the resulted sliced string. For `string = 'ABCDEFGHI'` this prints:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

And of course you can remove the hardcoded `3` with a variable, say `gap = 3` to make the loop more visually pleasing:

```
gap = 3
for i in range(gap, len(string) + 1, gap): 
    print string[i-gap: i]
```

Comment: Why start at `gap` instead of `0` with `print string[i:i+gap]`? -- This seems to be a little more what I would expect ...

Comment: That would actually make the counter go over the `len(string)+1` limit and index the `string` with `string[9:12]` (in this case). Of course changing `stop` to `len(string) - 1` does the trick, but, it seems less intuitive, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generator function like so:

```
def trios(seq):
    result = []
    for e in seq:
        result.append(e)
        if len(result) == 3:
            yield result
            result = []
    if result:
        yield result
```

And use it like so:

```
>>> string = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
>>> [t for t in trios(string)]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K']]
```

If the string is not divisible by three the final element will contain less than three characters.  If you'd rather it threw those away you could write the generator like so:

```
def trios(seq):
    result = []
    for e in seq:
        result.append(e)
        if len(result) == 3:
            yield result
            result = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`grouper` recipe on the `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) docs. As written, it returns `tuple`s, not new `str`s, but it's trivially adaptable:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

The only tweak is to wrap the final line to make it convert the `tuple`s `zip_longest` produces back to `str`:

```
    return map(''.join, izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue))
```